# The logo in the chat room didn't change .. is that normal?

Tags: discussion, logo

Well I was chatting with a user in the chatting room, and I noticed the logo isn't colored ..(it wasn't changed) is that normal ?

[image: normal]

[image: rainbow]

Comment: Given that it's the first time it's changed, there is really no "normal". It's probably not a malfunction though, just something that didn't get changed

Comment: @Pekka웃  I am just pointing out what I noticed. its up to you if to change it or not. the question .. should it be changed ? are there any other places where the logo hasn't change ?

Comment: Not me, I don't work for Stack Overflow. :) It probably shouldn't be changed - the logo should be back to normal by tomorrow anyway.

Comment: with your high rep I though your a moderator. anyway maybe for the next time..

Comment: @Moudiz: moderators are recognisable by the diamond next to their name. I'm a moderator, for example.

Comment: Though of course, moderators also don't technically work for Stack Overflow. They're ordinary users with slightly elevated powers. Only an employee could address what you're talking about.